# Retrieving data in firebase database without calling addValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can i get a specific data from firebase database without calling the addValueEventListener. In my code i'm successfully getting the data using firebase database but when i use a function that contains the `addValueListener` and call the function i can't get the data. Here is my code:

```
 for(CheckOut g: GroceryActivity.list){

        String pid = g.getPid();
        Log.i("PID", pid);
        getOriginalQuantity(pid);
        Log.i("Original_Quantity", "" + originalQuantity);}

 public void getOriginalQuantity(String pid){

    originalQuantityReference = originalQuantityReference.child(pid);

    originalQuantityReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Grocery grocery = dataSnapshot.getValue(Grocery.class);
            originalQuantity = grocery.getQuantity().toString();
            Log.i("Original Quantity", originalQuantity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}//end getOriginalQuantity method
```

I'm getting the correct data from the log in the `addValueListener` where in the the other log i'm getting null valeu

Comment: As others have said: the Firebase API (like most of the modern Cloud APIs) is asynchronous. The only way to use it synchronously would be to call its HTTPS REST API, but I **highly** recommend against that. The best you can do is get to grips with asynchronous programming. This will take time, but will give you the best results, and your user's the best apps. For a longer explanation, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase api is asynchronous meaning that when you use `AddValueEventListener` to retrieve data from the database, the program will not stop and continue executing. Therefore in this `log`:

```
Log.i("Original_Quantity", ""+originalQuantity);
```

You will get null since it is executed before the data is fully retrieved. There are two ways to access the data either inside the `onDataChange` or you can do the following:

[How to return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method)

Answer (score 2):

No, to get specific data from firebase database you must use addValueEventListener or addListenerForSingleValueEvent